# Finding the derived set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis

Let $E=([-1,0]- \mathbb{Q}) \cup \{ \frac{3n^2+2n}{(-1)^nn^2+n+1}: n\in \mathbb{N} \}$, I'm asked to find the derived set of E. What I did was the following. Considering $a_n=\frac{3n^2+2n}{(-1)^nn^2+n+1}$, we have $a_{2n} \rightarrow 3$ and $a_{2n-1} \rightarrow -3$, so -3 and 3 are elements of the derived set. Also, due to the density of $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, we have that given a rational number $q \in [-1,0]$, every neighbourhood $(q- \epsilon, q+ \epsilon)$ ($\epsilon >0$) contains infinitely many irrational numbers, so every point in $[-1,0] -\mathbb{Q}$ is in the derived set. In conclusion, the derived set should be $D(E)=([-1,0] -\mathbb{Q})\cup \{-3,3\}$ Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1):

Rational numbers and irrational numbers are both dense in the set of real number.

$$D(E)= [-1, 0] \cup \{-3, 3\}$$

Comment: Oops, you're right! I said that irrational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but eventually I did not include the rational numbers